# WordPress media library allow uploading fake file

Tags: hooks, security

I created a file with some string in it and rename it as `example.jpg`. This file is then uploaded via WordPress media library and it actually went through.

This can't be good, if same file contain malicious code like EICAR virus signature.

Is there a method to avoid this? I'm looking at `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` function but not sure if it's a correct method to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tested this using another account? WordPress makes speciai allowances for the site owner a lot of the time, and if you're a super admin or the only administrator on a site you're given extra trust

Comment: Also note that some plugins and themes may modify this behaviour

Comment: @baker did you found a way to fix the issue? i have the same problem with uploading eicar file

Comment: @sampaii sort of, intercept the uploader and have it check for magic number https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't an image, its mime type is checked against the allowed list.

As your example would generate a text mimetype, and it's an allowed file extension, it passes through. There should be no concern unless your server is executing image files as PHP, in which case this issue is the least of your concerns.

If you consider it a bug though, you should open a Trac ticket, this isn't the place for reporting WP bugs